# Underscore Create array of objects from object elements

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Hello I have object like this:

```
var obj = { banana: 1425, orange: 1683}
```

and I need array of objects created on the basis of items. 
for example:

```
[{name: banana, value: 1425}, {name: orange, value: 1683}]
```

I did it in this way :

```
var fruits = [];
_.each(obj, function(value, name){
    fruits.push({
        name: name,
        value: value
    });
});
```

maybe you know an easier way?

Comment: http://underscorejs.org/#pairs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use underscore's _.map on an object :

```
var obj = { banana: 1425, orange: 1683};

var fruits = _.map(obj, function(value, key){
  return { name : key, value : value };
});
```

http://underscorejs.org/#map

Answer (score 0):

You could also just use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```
let myobj = {banana: 1425, orange: 1683};
let entries = Object.entries(myobj); // => [['banana', 1425], ['orange', 1683]];


//and if you want it in array-object format:
let other_format = Object.entries(myobj).map(entry => {
    return {[entry[0]]: entry[1]}
}); // => [{banana: 1425}, {orange: 1683}]
```